# Shade smooth not working

Tags: smooth

I tried everything, it isn't marked as sharp and topology is okay[image: this edges]

Comment: hello could you please share this part of your mesh? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: done [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RQo4PbS1" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RQo4PbS1/)

Comment: The normals are backwards on circled areas. Recalculate normals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have custom normals or autosmooth enabled. And the usual things: flipped normals, double vertices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, please [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)